# Optimize my grep to search for "$DIR/www"?

Tags: linux, grep, find

I'm trying to do a case insensitive search for a URL through ~100 directories. The structure of each of these directories are:

```
directory/
  www
  logs
  cgi-bin
  emailer
```

Sometimes, `trunk` or `branches` instead of `www`, but that's the only difference.

How can I optimize my grep for `http://URL` in order to easily find this faster? So far, I have:

- changed LC_ALL/LANG to C ( case insensitive )
- implemented max depth and combined find/grep

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "www" -exec grep -RliI "http://URL" {} \; >> ~/results.txt
```

But i want to optimize it so that it doesnt hit these specific directories:

- www/cache
- www/images

I've tried this so far:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "www" -path -prune -o -name '*cache*' -exec grep -RliI "http://URL" {} \;
```

But it doesn't seem to prune it right? How can I adjust it so that it excludes?

Another note, the version of `grep` is old, so `--exclude-dir` isn't supported, otherwise I would use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-not -path` rather than `-prune`.

`find . -maxdepth 2 -name "www" -not -path "*/cache/*" -not -path "*/images/*" -exec grep -RliI "http://URL" {} \;`

Comment: I still get results. It finds: `./sitename_com/www/test/blah/file.php` and `./sitename_com/www/cache/file.php`

Comment: Ahh yes, the problem is that `find` is passing `./sitename_com/www` to `grep` which is then searching recursively, including the unwanted `cache` and `images` directories. 

Here's another (slightly convoluted) attempt that first finds the www directories, then finds all the subdirectories under them, then excludes the www/ directories themselves.

`find . -maxdepth 2 -name "www" | xargs  -I % find % -not -path "*images*" -not -path "*cache*" | egrep -v 'www$' | grep -RliI "http://URL"`

Comment: Hm, that returned empty. does the egrep in that account for `www` being under `sitename_com`? Sorry I'm running this find on the root of the `directory` in the example, not in `directory`.

Comment: I tried to recreate your directory structure, and for me it returned everything under `sitename/www/` except `cache` and `images`. I also started the find from the root. I'm not sure what else to say except to keep fine tuning based on these ideas.